# Using a Class Loader, how do I check Instance of For Two Classes

Tags: superclass, instanceof, urlclassloader, isinstance

So in my scenario I am using the URLClassLoader and I've loaded a directory containing class a, b and c.

class b extends class a, class c extends nothing.

How can I check this in my code I have been trying to use

b.isInstance(a) however this returns false, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies I should have been using

a.isAssignableFrom(b)

Works like a charm now. Thanks anyways.